# How to separate data and register it in a database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to separate the data that I get here and trying to register it in the database.

I get the data with a form that looks like this.

```js
var max_input_fields=10;
var delimiter='|';

function http( data, callback ){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ) callback.call( this, xhr.response );
    };
    xhr.open( 'POST', document.location.href, true );
    xhr.send( data );
}

function cbhttp(r){
    document.querySelectorAll('output')[0].innerHTML=r
}

function bindEvents(){
    var oBttnAdd=document.getElementById('bttnadd');
    var oBttnSub=document.getElementById('bttnsub');
    var oForm=document.getElementById('dynelems');
    var oParent=document.getElementById('loopdiv');

    oBttnSub.onclick=function(e){
        /* scan the form and get values from all elements ( including dynamcially added ) and submit the form via xhr */
        var col=oForm.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"],textarea,select');
        var data=new FormData();
            data.append('delimiter',delimiter);

        for( var n in col ) if( col[n] && col[n].nodeType==1 ) {
            data.append( col[n].name, col[n].value.replace( delimiter, '' ) + delimiter );
        }
        http.call( this, data, cbhttp );
    };

    oBttnAdd.onclick=function(e){
        /* Add new rows based upon selected option from dropdown menu */
        var col=oParent.querySelectorAll('section[data-id]');
        var length=col.length;
        if( length < max_input_fields ){
            var newid=parseInt( col[ length-1 ].dataset.id ) + 1;
            var clone=oParent.childNodes[1].cloneNode( true );
                clone.dataset.id=newid;
                /* Set new name for the textarea */
                clone.childNodes[3].childNodes[1].name='videolink'+newid;

            oParent.appendChild( clone );
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents,false);
```

```html
<form action="adddilemman.php" id="dynelems" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <br>
    <div id='loopdiv'>
            <?php
                /* Data-id is used by js to determine next suitable id */
                echo "
                    <section data-id=1>
                        <h2>Dilemma</h2>
                        <div>Video länk:<br><textarea rows='1' cols='40' name='videolink1'></textarea></div>";

                for( $i=1; $i <= 4; $i++ ){

                    /* Add four text fields and four select menus */
                    echo "
                        <div>
                            Answer: <input type='text' name='answer{$i}[]'/>
                            <select name='options{$i}[]'>";

                    /* Add options to each select menu */
                    for( $j=1; $j <= 10; $j++ ){
                        echo "<option value={$j}>{$j}";
                    }

                    /* Close each nested div & select menu */
                    echo "
                            </select>
                        </div>";
                }
                /* Close initial section */
                echo "
                    </section>";

            ?>
            </div>

            <div class='input_fields_wrap'>
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <input id='bttnadd' type='button' name='add_field_button' value='Lägg till fler svar'/>
            <input id='bttnsub' type='submit' name='sub' value='Submit'/>
        </form>
        <output></output>
```

I'm using "adddilemman.php" to show the data just to see if its working and its working. But I have now idea how to register this data in the database. PS I want to register it in two different tables (textarea in a table and answers in another table)

```html
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();
        /* This is here only to simplify development and display here */

        $delimiter=isset( $_POST['delimiter'] ) ? $_POST['delimiter'] : '|';

        /* process form submission: for testing purposes just echo out data sent */
        foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ) {
            if( $field!='delimiter' ){
                if( is_array( $value ) ) echo 'Array values: '.$field.'='.rtrim( str_replace( $delimiter, ',', implode( ' ', $value ) ), ',' ).'<br />';
                else echo 'String value: '.$field.'='.trim( str_replace( $delimiter, '', $value ) ).'<br />';
            }
        }

        exit();
    }
?>
```

Any recommendations how I can separate this data and register it in the database?

Comment: What does your MySQL table look like? Please provide an example of the data you're needing to work with. Which do you wish to use: PDO or MySQLi? What code have you tried?

Comment: @Twisty You can see my code in the next comment

Answer (score 0):

You would want to setup the form like so:

```
<textarea rows='1' cols='40' name='videolink1'><?php echo isset($_POST['videolink1'])?$_POST['videolink1']:""; ?></textarea>
<?php
for( $i=1; $i < 5; $i++ ){
/* Add four text fields and four select menus */
?>
        <div>
            <label>Answer:</label>
            <input type='text' name='answer[<?php echo $i; ?>]' value="<?php echo isset($answer[$i])?$answer[$i]:''; ?>" />
                <select name='options[<?php echo $i; ?>]'>
<?php
     for( $j=1; $j <= 10; $j++ ){
        if($options[$i] == $j){
            echo "\t\t\t\t\t<option selected='selected' value={$j}>{$j}</option>\r\n";
         } else {
             echo "\t\t\t\t\t<option value={$j}>{$j}</option>\r\n";
         }
    }
?>
                </select>
            </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I would prepare the post data like so:

```
<?php
$vidlink = "";
$answers = array();
$options = array();
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    $vidlink = htmlentities($_POST['videolink1']);
    for($i=1;$i<=count($_POST['answer']);$i++){
        $answer[$i] = $_POST['answer'][$i];
        $options[$i] = $_POST['options'][$i];
    }
}
?>
```

This will place the content of the answers and options in their own arrays but with the same indexes. You can loop and place them in the DB any way you like. Here is an example:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "wildfire");

if($con === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
for($i=1;$i<=$count($answer);$i++){
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO answer_det ('aid', 'answer', 'points') VALUES (?, ?, ? )")) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isi", $i, $answer[$i], $options[$i]);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
```

Here is all the code I used for testing on phpfiddle.org:

```
<?php
$vidlink = "";
$answers = array();
$options = array();
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    $vidlink = htmlentities($_POST['videolink1']);
    for($i=1;$i<=count($_POST['answer']);$i++){
        $answer[$i] = $_POST['answer'][$i];
        $options[$i] = $_POST['options'][$i];
    }
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="dynelems" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id='loopdiv'>
                <section data-id=1>
                    <h2>
                        Dilemma
                    </h2>
                    <div>
                        Video länk:
                        <br />
                        <textarea rows='1' cols='40' name='videolink1'><?php echo isset($_POST['videolink1'])?$_POST['videolink1']:""; ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <?php
for( $i=1; $i < 5; $i++ ){
    /* Add four text fields and four select menus */
                    ?>
                    <div>
                        <label>Answer:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='answer[<?php echo $i; ?>]' value="<?php echo isset($answer[$i])?$answer[$i]:''; ?>" />
                        <select name='options[<?php echo $i; ?>]'>
                            <?php
    for( $j=1; $j <= 10; $j++ ){
        if($options[$i] == $j){
            echo "\t\t\t\t\t<option selected='selected' value={$j}>{$j}</option>\r\n";
        } else {
            echo "\t\t\t\t\t<option value={$j}>{$j}</option>\r\n";
        }
    }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <?php
}
                    ?>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class='input_fields_wrap'>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input id='bttnadd' type='button' name='add_field_button' value='Lägg till fler svar'/>
            <input id='bttnsub' type='submit' name='sub' value='Submit'/>
        </form>
        <output>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    htmlentities(var_export($_POST));
    var_export($answer);
    var_export($options);
}
        </output>
</html>
```